# Why does Youtube set flash movies to wmode=window by default?

Tags: iframe, youtube, wmode

I understand the option can be controlled, but I'm sure there's a ton of people who's copy and pasting of embed codes skills do not extend as far as adding wmode=opaque into the iframe SRC attribute.

I'm curious as to what benefit having "window" as the default mode gives over "opaque" or "transparent" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the other modes are more browser error prone and that screen readers have problems accessing the content.

Here are some examples:

- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-908
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-892
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-501
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1181
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-110